# SOAP HTTP Parameter Cookie Java

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to invoke a Web Service using the Java API javax.xml.soap.* with this code:

```
QName serviceName = new QName("xxx","xxx", "xxx");
QName portName = new QName("xxx","xxx","xxx");
String endpointAddress = "xxx";
Service service = Service.create(serviceName);
service.addPort(portName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING,endpointAddress);
Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch =  service.createDispatch(portName,SOAPMessage.class,Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) dispatch;
...
```

It works perfectly, I just want to know how to pass the the Cookie value on the HTTP header of this request?
The webservice is configured with security and I'm not able to login.

Thanks!

João

Answer (score 1):

```
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) dispatch;

        bp.getRequestContext().put(
                MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,
                Collections.singletonMap("Cookie", Collections
                        .singletonList("xxx")));
```

This is the code to set the Header parameters.

I was using strange .jars provided by SAP, that was the problem.

Thanks